# using gdb with piped input without creating file

Tags: gdb

I have a program that takes in piped input:

```
bash> echo "something" | ./program 'seomthingelse'
```

How can I redirect this input into gdb, WITHOUT creating a new file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I redirect this input into gdb, WITHOUT creating a new file?

- You can create a named pipe (not sure whether this counts as a "new file" or not -- *why* are you trying to avoid a new file?)
- You can put a delay into the program, start it with `echo "something" | ./program 'seomthingelse'`, and attach to it from another window while it is still being in the delay.

The second solution is often quite useful for programs that are very particular about how they are invoked, and I find the following implementation to work well:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (getenv("WAIT_FOR_GDB") != NULL) {
    int done = 0;
    while (!done) sleep(1);
  }
  /* rest of main */
}
```

Then you set `WAIT_FOR_GDB` in the environment, and can take arbitrary time to attach the process. Once attached, step `up` from `sleep`, `set var done = 1`, set any other breakpoints you need, and `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gdbserver` for this. stdin will be available, unmodified, to the target program.

In one terminal session:

```
bash> echo "something" | gdbserver ./program 'seomthingelse'
Process ./program created; pid = 1591
Listening on port 1234
```

At this point, `./program` has been paused, just after it was started.

In another terminal session:

```
bash> gdb ./program
(gdb) target remote localhost:1234
Remote debugging using localhost:1234
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
0x48611020 in _start () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb)
```

`gdbserver` may be in your distro's `gdb` package, or you may need to install another package. On Fedora, it's `gdb-gdbserver`.